# How to pass data between activities that don't follow one another

Tags: android-studio

I have a scenario where I want to keep the username value I entered in my login activity and send this
value, not to the following activity `Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SecondActivity.this)`, but to another activity further in the app`ThirdActivity` or `FourthActivity`.
So basically the question is how do you pass data between non successive activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple you can add Shared Preferences in your login activity add the following code

First, make a constant

```
public static final String USERNAME = "0";//Write this at the start

//Then add this inside a function 
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("username", 0);
Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString(USERNAME, username);//username is your username.
editor.apply();
```

Then maybe in your third/fourth activity add this in function onCreate()

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("username", 0);
String Username = sharedPreferences.getString(USERNAME, "");
//Now you can use the String Username wherever you want
```

Comment: Good to know that.

Comment: Would appreciate if the answer was approved so that it maybe helpful for future users

Comment: Ok I did it just now